# Laracasts tutorial issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laragon

EDIT/Solution : I seem to have found the culprit. I was using the live server extension for Visual Studio, and it turns out it doesn't serve Laravel the same was as artisan does. solution is to use artisan, though will see if I can get the auto reload of Live server to fuction.

I am doing the Laracasts tutorial seem to be running into a few issues.
Originally I thought it had to do with me working on Windows, but the coding shouldn't change this much.

firstly my 'a href' only works when using the full blade name rather than just the shorthand 'post', like so:

```
<h1><a href="post.blade.php">My First Post</a></h1>
```

Second the roots file 'a href="/"' doesnt work and I get the error:

```
"The requested resource / was not found on this server."
```

It only works again by using the full blade name, like so:

```
<a href="posts.blade.php">Go Back</a>
```

Is this normal behaviour?

Now when trying to parse the 'post' variable I get the error:

```
"Notice: Undefined variable: post in C:\laragon\www\blog\resources\views\post.blade.php on line 10"
```

My code is as follows
web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    //return 'hello';
    return view('posts');
});

Route::get('post', function () {
    
    return view('post',  [
        'post' => '<h1>Hello World</h1>'
    ]);
      
});
```

post.blade.php

```
<!doctype html>

<title>My Blog</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="\public\app.css">

<body>
    <article>
    <?=$post;?>
    </article>

    <a href="posts.blade.php">Go Back</a>
</body>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I cannot continue till I have resolved these issues.

Comment: Run `php artisan route:list` to get a route list. It would give a better way to use the `/`.

Comment: Hi @SachinBahukhandi, thanks for the response. I ran the command, but I am not sure what I am looking for. I see '/' listed under 'URI' with action Closure.

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi it seems I found the issue. it was my VSCode live server extension that hosted the files differently